# Error: "'node' not recognized as..." when I try to run the file with package.json script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am learning Node, and I get the error "node is not recognized as an internal or external command" when I try to run my project with `npm start` or `npm run start`. It works if I use `node index.js`. I have checked the Node Environment Variables, my Node version is v16.13.2 and npm is 8.4.1.
My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "node-express-practica",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.2",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "@babel/register": "^7.17.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running command as administrator should work for you.